# Bootstrap разная ширина на телефоне и компьютере

Tags: css, bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap5

Как сделать, чтобы на ПК div был 50% в ширину, а на телефоне - 100?

Comment: `.col-12`, `.col-md-6`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```